# Right approximations for special modules in Frobenius algebras

Tags: rt.representation-theory, homological-algebra

Let $A$ be a commutative Frobenius algebra (we can assume $A$ is also local) given by quiver and relations.

Let $M_i=A/p_iA$ be a module where $p_i$ is a path in Q.
Let $N:=A \oplus \bigoplus\limits_{i=1}^{r}{M_i}$.

> Question: Is there a nice way to describe a minimal $add(N)$ right approximation of an indecomposable $A$-module $X$ (we can assume $X$ is a submodule of $X$ in case that helps)?